# Running into problems with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, service, mockito

I've been trying to get some unit tests working using Mockito. I'm working in a Netbeans project, Java EE 8. I'm trying to build a web application with multiple layers. So far the domain and the dao layer are working fine and the service layer itself is not giving me any errors. However, I'm now running into trouble running the service layer's tests using Mockito.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Running service.WeaponsmithServiceTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.154 sec <<< FAILURE!
testCreate(service.WeaponsmithServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.056 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:167)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:109)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:105)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:70)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:95)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:49)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1285)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.process(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:66)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:71)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:55)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:108)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl$1.withBefores(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:319)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @33833882
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$2.run(ReflectUtils.java:57)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:47)
    ... 49 more


Results :

Tests in error: 
  testCreate(service.WeaponsmithServiceTest)
```

This is the ServiceTest I'm trying to run:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class WeaponsmithServiceTest {
    
    private WeaponsmithService service;
    @Mock
    private WeaponsmithDaoJPA weaponsmithDao;
    
    Weaponsmith weaponsmith;
    
    public WeaponsmithServiceTest() {
    }
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        service = new WeaponsmithService();
        service.setDao(weaponsmithDao);
        weaponsmith = new Weaponsmith("name", "password");
        
    }

    
    @Test
    public void testCreate() throws Exception {
        service.create(weaponsmith);
        verify(weaponsmithDao, Mockito.times(1)).create(weaponsmith);
    }
```

This here is my Dao implementation

```
public class WeaponDaoJPA extends DaoImpl<Weapon> implements WeaponDao {

    @Override
    public List<Weapon> findByGoldCost(int goldCost) {
        TypedQuery<Weapon> query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("weapon.findByGoldCost", Weapon.class).setParameter("goldCost", goldCost);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Weapon> findByName(String name) {
        TypedQuery<Weapon> query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("weapon.findByName", Weapon.class).setParameter("name", name);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
    
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something that in hindsight will make me say "Oh, right." but I've been on it for a bit and I just can't figure it out, help would be appreciated!

If you need anything else from me, feel free to let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is a problem with java modules, so depending on how you are running your tests you may consider e.g. java-arg `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` or the maven config provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50634322/java-modules-accessibility-problems-for-mockito-2-20-0 - does one of these help?

Comment: @fladdimir Thanks for the response! I tried the maven config provided in that link, but no luck! What would another way be to implement that "--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED" line?